# Why won't grep functions work on localhost?

Tags: php, regex

```
$grep=preg_grep("/^(\d+)?\.\d+$/", "11.11");
print_r($grep);
```

Shouldn't this be printing an array consisting of "11.11"?

Comment: And shouldn't *you* be enabling `error_reporting` when something doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

No...you want to use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)... [`preg_grep` is for arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php):

```
if(preg_match("/^(\d+)?\.\d+$/", "11.11", $matches)) {
   print_r($matches);
} else {
   echo "No Match!";
}
```